# WordPress Upload Media to a post issue

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, upload, centos, media

I'm struggling from an error on WordPress 3.8.1.

Whenever I try to upload a media to a post, it does not add, it says `An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.`.

But the weirder thing is that it is shown on dashboard/media/library even after this issue.

I also cannot see uploaded attached media to my posts (edit post / [add media button]) / media library / uploaded to this post, but in dashboard/media/library section , these old uploaded images are shown properly that which is uploaded to what post.

I have tried the followings:

- Re-installed both my local version and en_US from both update manager and manually
- Deleted `wp-includes` and `wp-admin` folders and replaced them manually.
- I have checked chown and chmod of the `wp-content/uploads` folder. To make sure they are working, I have deleted `wp-content/uploads/2014` folder, and after first upload that shows this error, the folder is created with right chown and chmod and files were there (`wp-content/uploads/2014/01/26/file with resolutions.jpg`)
- I have deleted unneeded plugins, deactivated all plugins and themes, switched back to WordPress's default plugin, I have even reset active plugins json object at wp_options from SQL, did not help.
- I have enabled php error logs, nothing related is shown
- I have altered the `WP_DEBUG` definition to `true`, I have even defined `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` to `true`, no help.
- When I try to add from `wp-admin/media-new.php` , using multi uploader, file is freezing at "`Crunching…`" step, but old browser upload works flawlessly.
- I'm managing the VPS and hosting the blog myself with CentOS 6.5 x64. `safe_mode` is set as `off`. There is not a `mod_security` option in my php.ini. My `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini` is set to `20M`, `memory_limit` is `256M`, only 3 sites are hosted and memory is quite empty while testing these. This also happens even with 50kb .jpg images, so this should not be related.
- I have re-uploaded all wordpress files from a clean downloaded zip, no help.
- I have tried adding `AddType x-mapp-php5 .php .php4` to the end of `.htaccess` as suggested [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/media-uploader-freezes-at-crunching-or-doesnt-even-crunch-at-all), that did not help at all.

*The thing is that, I have tried a clean installation to another domain on the same server, it is working as it should.*

What could be the problem? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you check the user and group owners of the wordpress tree? Also, are you getting that the "uploading" bar goes to 100%, and *then* shows the error? Are your uploaded images getting all of their thumbnails generated properly? Check the wp-uploads and the Media panel to see if they are.

Comment: "When I try to add from wp-admin/media-new.php , using multi uploader, file is freezing at "Crunching…" step, but old browser upload works flawlessly.", could you tell me what goes on on your "Network" tab for Firebug, Inspector, whatever while you do this?

Comment: @Alainus no errors at all. I have already checked. Also group and owners are correct. Weird, when I truncate the wp_posts table, it uploads correctly. But I'm not sure what's causing that error.

Answer (score 2):

See if custom post type has any files that are in UTF-8. If you change it to ANSI, that should help, if thats an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and found that there is a problem with my theme itself... try doing the same action using the twentyten theme. if that works, then take a look and see if there is any conflicting code in the functions.php of the theme...

if you are using a child theme can I suggest making another child theme, or using an alternative them as in my experience not all themes "like" being used as a child...

Comment: Sadly, the issue was still there with default theme + all themes uninstalled in my case. I've ended up by doing a clean install and re-importing blog entries.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to upload into a custom post-type, change the capability_type setting in your functions.php file to 'post' and it should fix your problem.

Comment: No, I'm not having this issue on custom post type. This happens directly while writing a default blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions of your wp-content or wp-content/upload folders, If folder permission is not 755 then change it to 755 and re-upload again. I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: It was not the issue. Permissions were correct, and as I've mentioned, with legacy upload it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue in wordpress like media not loaded in popup. then i have resolved.

I think, Some times problem created by ajax response.Means ajax response comes with some additional content.

Wordpress media popup is loaded content by ajax(json Response) and ajax give response with some content like style and other.

**For Example:-**

```
<style>
.class{}
</style>
then json(ajax response).
```

So First check your ajax response in console.We have to disable all plugins then check it is work or not.If no then activate default theme. because content comes from plugin and theme.

Comment: None of these worked. No message given on console, I've already deactivated all my plugins. I've also fallen back to default theme, it was all the same. I've made a posts backup and reinstalled. It solved the problem for me

Comment: Some file doesn't upload because that's work with ajax and js. if ajax response with some other text then some error occurs in **json format**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a low scale server and added a plugin named "`WP-SmushIt`" then it will surely cause an error. Reason is simple this plugin uses CPU resources to minimize the size of images in process of optimizing it and so it crosses the server limited execution time. Solution is simple-> Go with higher plan servers or try changing server execution time listed in php config file.

Comment: Thanks, I did not use that plugin, and I was chekcking system resources and there was not a peak of neither memory nor cpu usage during this stage.

The machine has 8 cores x 3GB each, and 6GBs of ram, also fpm and nginx configurations were allowing to use all these resources, so I don't think it was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to this, but I have experienced the exact same issue after moving the very same site to a different server now. Only difference is now I've been using Nginx instead of Apache. I have checked the ownerships before and they were all correct (else the normal upload wouldn't work earlier either). I'm leaving this here just as a reference.

The fix on my newer case was simply changing the ownership of the web root and all the files inside.

Nginx and PHP5-FPM were running with same user: `www-data`, which is at the group with same name: `www-data`.

So changing of all the ownership of the files fixed in this case:

```
su
chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/wordpress/root/
```

And the issue was gone.

I still don't know the original reason of my old issue, I had to wipe, start from clean and restore the posts, plugins etc. from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

check your folder permission, and mod_security settings, also try to increase max_execution_time and memory,

Comment: Have you read what I've tried? They are all accurate. Folder has the right permission, as I've said, it "uploads and creates the folder", it saves the image, but it does not redirect to the state success. I've also increased max_execution time, and mod_security option is correct. This even happens on 20x20 jpg files with only 10 kb. Also a new clean installation of Wordpress on same machine works flawlessly. This is more table related I guess.

Comment: hm, i had this same issue , i solved it after updating the folder permissions and uninstalled few plugin, but your case its strange, if the site is not big/under development its better to re-install the WordPress